# Running Android without VM

Tags: android, linux, dalvik

It's almost an exact copy of a question from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/removing-dalvik-from-android). Sorry for this, but the audience here is much larger so I have better chance to get a precise answer.

Is it possible to remove all "user layer" application and VM from Android, just to obtain plain linux-based embedded OS with all libraries and drivers already configured? Since VM is just a process from kernel's perspective...

Looking on [this](http://source.android.com/devices/index.html) what I would like to get is: Linux kernel + HAL + (maybe) a shell or some way to launch my program.

Maybe somebody already have done something like this or knows good resources about it?

Comment: You might want to explain where you intend to run this. XYZ ARM dev board would probably already have a standard Linux env image.

Comment: It's just curiosity. And I wanted to hack a bit my old mobile phone - instead of buying XYZ ARM dev board. But in generall, you're totally right.

Comment: Android recovery mode is basically this. You get all the kernel stuff, the basic Linux OS and a bit of graphics, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks, that can be useful hint!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (Though I never tried and not 100% sure). To do this, you have to get the source code of Android (Android is open source, so its easy to get it) and start removing all user layer application and VM. Then, you need to write a program to operate the device. Its hard to do it though.